# Windows 8 Metro Inapp purchases for Dummies

Tags: javascript

am ready to deploy my second windows 8 metro style javascript app and i would love to include in app purchases.
I tried implementing it with the following code i got from here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694067.aspx

```
function appInit()
{
  // some app initialization functions

    // Get current product object 
    // Execute only one of these statements. 
    // The next line is commented out for testing.
    // currentApp = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp;

    // The next line is commented out for production/release.
    currentApp = Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentAppSimulator;

    // We should have either a real or a simulated CurrentProduct object here.

    // Get the license info
    licenseInformation = currentApp.licenseInformation;

  // other app initializations function
 }
 function buyFeature1() {
    if (!licenseInformation.productLicenses.lookup("featureName").isActive)
      {

        currentApp.requestProductPurchaseAsync("featureName", false).then(
           function () {
            // the in-app purchase was successful
            }, 
           function () {
            // The in-app purchase was not completed because // there was an error.
        });
    } 
    else
    {
    // The customer already owns this feature.
    }
   }
```

But nothing seems to happen.i know this is a novice question. but i'l be glad if someone can provide a full simple working solution.Btw i've read the docs and downloaded the sample.i also have my storeproxy.xml file setup.

Answer (score 1):

You might try changing:

```
currentApp.requestProductPurchaseAsync("featureName", false).then(
```

Into:

```
currentApp.requestProductPurchaseAsync("featureName", false).done(
```

That is what I use and it works for me.